# insert into statements,how to be fastly insert records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If i have a 1 million insert into statement in text file then how to be inserted in a table with faster time.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (1,'shubham','engg');
INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (2,'swapnil','chemical');

INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (n,'n','n');
```

like in above we have 1 million rows. how to be fastly insert records in a table If any other options is there else simply run above all statement in sequency.

Comment: RDMS tags MySQL and Oracle database can't exists in one question, atleast not in this question as multi insert is different a cross these RDMS.. Oracle database uses `INSERT ALL
INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (...) INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (...) [, ....] SELECT * FROM dual` Where MySQL uses `INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES (...), (...) [, ...]`

Comment: I presume you've wrongly tagged mysql, which definitely is unrelated to oracle & oracle11g.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid row by row inserts for dumping such huge quantities of data. They are pretty slow and there's no reason you should rely on the plain inserts, even if you're utilising SQL* Plus command line to run it as a file. Put the values to be inserted as  comma(or any other delimiter) separated entries in a flat file and then use options such as

- [**SQL Loader**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm)
- [**External table**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)

It is a common practice to extract data into flat files from tools like SQL Developer. Choose the "CSV" option instead of "Insert" that will generate the values in a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

If it means that your text file contains literally those `INSERT INTO` statements, then run the file.

- If you use GUI, load the file and run it as a script (so that it executes them all).
- If you use SQL*Plus, call the file using `@`, e.g.

  ```
  SQL> @insert_them_all.sql
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a batch insert on single query statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b,c) VALUES
(1,'shubham','engg'),
(2,'swapnil','chemical'),
(n,'n','n');
```